# Some Images wont load in html, while others work fine for no obvious reason

Tags: html

why does html just not recognize some images? i took a picture on my phone and moved it to my laptop, and when i try to load it nothing happens. images that i edit in gimp dont work unless i upload them to am image sharing site and redownload them, and sometimes even that doesnt work. i know it isnt an issue with my syntax, because some other images will load, just not the ones i actually want. ive tried to adjust the image permissions, images will have the same permissions but only some of them work.

i know this isnt a lot to go off of, if anything else is needed ill try my best to answer

Comment: You should provide specific examples. Show us some code.

Comment: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.jpg" type="image/x-icon">`

another image like portrait.png, which has same chmod permissions and is in the same folder loads just fine as a favicon

Comment: `image/x-icon` is for `.ico` format files. You're trying to load a JPG. Try `image/jpg` instead.

Comment: tried, still nothing